# XMLHttpRequest cannot load Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

In my Angular app below is the error I'm getting when I try to login while developing locally (Chrome):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.tickertags.com/app/api/login. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:8100'
that is not equal to the supplied origin.
Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The login function from my loginController

```
function login(credentials) {
    console.log('credentials',credentials);
    AuthFactory.login(credentials).then(function (user) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
        $scope.setCurrentUser(user);

        if (user.password_reset) {
            $location.path('/password');
        } else {
            $location.path('/tickers');
        }
    }, function () {
        console.log('"Invalid Username/Password"');
        $scope.loginData.message = "Invalid Username/Password";
        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
    }, function () {
        console.log('"Invalid Username/Password"');
        $scope.loginData.message = "Invalid Username/Password";
        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
    });
}
```

The `AuthFactory.login` function hits an API that is hosted on production. I'm not sure what I'm missing? This is what my localhost link looks like http://localhost/static/manage/v2/#/login

Comment: Look at all the ***related questions*** on right side of this page. Every one of them is same topic. Issue comes up numerous times a day here and is not hard to research

Comment: Yeah I've gone through about 5 of them so far, none I feel answer my question :( I see there are more, going through them now

Comment: None of the code you've shared with us sets the origin header, so we can't tell why it is setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to `http://localhost:8100` instead of `http://localhost`

Comment: important to note that different port is considered different origin in most browsers

Comment: A different port is considered a different origin in all browsers. That is what the spec says. It isn't considered a different domain because it isn't one.

Comment: @Quentin right...always have `cross domain` in my head. IE however doesn't seem to care for some reason..if it's only a port mismatch

Comment: I figured out my problem, I was trying to hit an absolute path with my API call to login ie: `www.tickertags.com/api/...` instead of just `/api/...` that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps someone else who is running into this problem, and can't access anything on the server side.

I figured out my problem, I was trying to hit an absolute path with my API call to login ie: `www.tickertags.com/api/...` instead of just `/api/...` that fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

To surpass CORS problem, you have to configure both front-end and back-end.

For front-end, when you call the `myApp.run()` method on the initialization you can configure default HTTP headers:

```
$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

For the back-end part you'll need to modify request headers. I don't know what's on your back-end, but I usually use these on my local Node server.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
 });
```